# Jnlp gives error in certification

Tags: java, security, jnlp, java-web-start, next-generation-plugin

I have generated the keystore and its inner key. Then I have my signed java applet. But each time I start my jnlp applet I can see the Internet browser security Warning dialog. When the application server and the client machine are in the same network , in the dialog box shows "Publisher: MyCompanyName "but when we access the application form the internet,it shows that "Publisher: UNKNOWN".

Anyone could let me know what the cause of this problem.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your digital certificate was created by you by typing details into prompts from the SDK tools, right?  It was not produced by a certification authority that verified those identity details.

The problem with the certificate you created is that I, or anyone else, could pretend to be you.  It is for that reason that the JRE refuses to identify who you ***claim*** to be - the information is worthless.

The fix is simple.  Get a certificate that has been verified by one of the recognized authorities, and sign the code using that certificate.

Comment: i see..so can you recommend any certificate that i can choose?is there any trial that i can use to before i purchase any of these?

Comment: 1) I use self signed certificates (much cheaper) & explain to my users that I cannot afford to get a verified certificate for distributing free apps.  They can take it or leave it.  2) Not that I know of.  I recall Thawte used to offer 'FreeMail' certs. for well, free.  Unfortunately 1) they were titled something like 'Freemail Cert.' rather than 'Our Company' 2) Verisign bought Thawte(?) some years ago & the offer of Freemail certs. vanished.

Comment: whoa..so this means that i NEED to buy that certificate first even when i just need to test it.
hm..that will cost me a lot of bucks..
is there other alternatives?

Comment: *"i just need to test it."*  Test **what*** exactly? Use a self-signed cert. for testing the app. itself.  The verified cert. will behave as I described. *"is there other alternatives?"*  The answer to that was covered in my 1st comment.  How many ways do you want me to say the same thing? :/