# Integrate signed applet in java web application

Tags: java, security, applet, signed-applet

I have a java applet project whichs starts a webcam and displays it on a window. I am trying to integrate this applet into my web-app, for that I have exported my applet as a JAR and included in my web-app and used it on my JSP page by using applet tag. Now I got a message that the digital signature cannot be verified. I am currently trying to sign my applet and use it, but I don't find any tutorials for that.

Can somebody please guide me that?

What I am trying to do is legal or can I try some other way to integrate my applet into JSP page or any other way to have webcam capture functionality in Java web application.

Comment: You should be able to do that. What issues you are facing? If you google it, you'll get plenty of resources on signed applets.

Comment: I have googled it and got the applet project from 
http://www.colorfulwolf.com/blog/2011/07/05/accessing-the-webcam-from- inside-a-java-applet/ this link. My applet's UI got loaded successfully but I can't get the webcam bar code scanner to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jnlp gives error in certification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986799/jnlp-gives-error-in-certification)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sign a Java applet for use in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908748/how-do-i-sign-a-java-applet-for-use-in-a-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emm... I do suppose so when you 'exported' your applet to JAR the signature became invalid or something; actually any modifications make it invalid... so I guess you need to

- A) As a tip, first clean your JRE certificates cache *(then try to restart your JSP;
  if it won't do then read B,C points)*
- B) Pack your (with blank manifest) applet into JAR
- C) If you have the [keystore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#Commands) sign the applet JAR with [jarsigner util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html)

---

Report if that helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign an applet jar before running it as an applet. This is a link for your reff.:
*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html*
Once jar is signed you can run it, if it still does not work try options for running signed content under: control Panel: Java